# Integrating $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, integration

I am working on trying to solve this problem:

> Prove: $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\frac{1}{n} \cos{x} \cdot \sin^{n - 1}{x} + \frac{n - 1}{n} \int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \ dx$

Here are the steps that I follow in the example that I am reading:

> $u = \sin^{n - 1}{x}$
>
> $du = (n - 1) \cdot \sin^{n - 2}{x} \cdot \cos{x} \ dx$
>
> $v = -\cos{x}$
>
> $dv = \sin{x} \ dx$
>
> ---
>
> $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx =  \sin^{n - 1}{x} \cdot \sin{x} \ dx$
>
> $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = \underbrace{\sin^{n - 1}{x}}_{u} \cdot \underbrace{-\cos{x}}_{v} - \int \underbrace{-\cos{x}}_{v} \cdot \underbrace{(n - 1) \cdot \sin^{n - 2}{x} \cdot \cos{x} \ dx}_{du}$
>
> $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\cos{x} \cdot \sin^{n - 1}{x} + (n - 1)\int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \cdot \cos^{2}{x} \ dx$
>
> $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\cos{x} \cdot \sin^{n - 1}{x} + (n - 1)\int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \cdot \left(1 - \sin^{2}{x}\right) \ dx$

Here is where I get lost. How did we go from $\int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \cdot \left(1 - \sin^{2}{x}\right) \ dx$ to $\int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \ dx - (n - 1) \int \sin^{n}{x} \ dx$? Even more specifically, where did $\sin^{n}{x}$ come from?

> $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\cos{x} \cdot \sin^{n - 1}{x} + (n - 1)\int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \ dx - (n - 1) \int \sin^{n}{x} \ dx$

I get this part.

> $n\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\cos{x} \cdot \sin^{n - 1}{x} + (n - 1)\int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \ dx$
>
> $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\frac{1}{n} \cos{x} \cdot x \ \sin^{n - 1}{x} + \frac{n - 1}{n} \int \sin^{n - 2}{x} \ dx$

Could someone please explain what I am missing?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Looks like he just cleared the parentheses, then split the integral into 2.

Comment: $\sin^{n-2}x\sin^2x=\sin^nx$

Comment: ohhh... then the $(n - 1)$ was distributed when the integral was broken up, I guess that is what was throwing me off. Thanks, Mike!

Comment: ... and Gerry!!

Comment: I think you might have an extra x in the first term of the answer (by mistake)  See the answer below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First let us denote

$$I_n = \int \sin^n{x} \ dx $$

$$ \int u(x) v'(x) dx = u(x) v(x) - \int v(x) u' (x) dx $$

Here $u(x) = \sin^{n-1}{x} \hspace{3pt}$ and $\hspace{3pt} v'(x) = \sin x $

$ \Rightarrow v(x) = -\cos x$

Therefo‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌re‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌
$$
\begin{align*}
I_n &= -\cos x \hspace{3pt} \sin^{n-1}x + \int \cos^2 x \hspace{4pt} (n-1) \sin^{n-2} x \hspace{4pt} dx \\
    &= -\cos x \hspace{3pt} \sin^{n-1}x + (n-1) \int \sin^{n-2} x \hspace{4pt} dx - (n-1) \int \sin^{n} dx\\
    &= -\cos x \hspace{3pt} \sin^{n-1}x + (n-1) \int \sin^{n-2} x \hspace{4pt} dx - (n-1) I_n
\end{align*}
$$

$$ \Rightarrow (1+n-1)I_n = -\cos x \hspace{3pt} \sin^{n-1}x + (n-1) \int \sin^{n-2} x dx $$

$$ \Rightarrow I_n = \frac{-\cos x \hspace{3pt} \sin^{n-1}x}{n} + \frac{(n-1)}{n} \int \sin^{n-2} x dx $$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct expansion.

Since
$e^{ix}
=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$,
$\sin(x)
=\frac12(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})
=\frac12e^{ix}(1-e^{-2ix})
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
\sin^n(x)
&=\frac1{2^n}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})^n\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{ikx}(-1)^{n-k}e^{-i(n-k)x}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}e^{i(2k-n)x}\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}(\cos((2k-n)x)+i\sin((2k-n)x))\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\cos((2k-n)x)
\qquad\text{since the sum is real}\\
\text{so}\\
I_n(x)
&=\int \sin^n(x)dx\\
&=\int\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\cos((2k-n)x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\int\cos((2k-n)x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{n-k}\dfrac{\sin((2k-n)x)}{2k-n}
\qquad\text{except at } 2k=n\\
I_{2n}(x)
&=\int \sin^{2n}(x)dx\\
&=\int\frac1{2^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{2n-k}\cos((2k-2n)x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{2n-k}\int\cos((2k-2n)x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n)x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n)x)dx+\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^{n}\int\cos(0)dx+\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n)x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n)x)dx+\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^{n}x+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{2n-k}(-1)^{2n-k}\int\cos((2(2n-k)-2n)x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n)x)dx+\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^{n}x+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2n-2k)x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n}}\left(2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n)x)dx+\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^{n}x\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n}}\left(2\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\dfrac{\sin((2k-2n)x)}{2k-2n}+\binom{2n}{n}(-1)^{n}x\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}(-1)^{k}\dfrac{\sin((2k-2n)x)}{2k-2n}+\binom{2n}{n}\dfrac{(-1)^{n}x}{2^{2n}}\\
I_{2n-1}(x)
&=\int \sin^{2n-1}(x)dx\\
&=\int\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{2n-1-k}\cos((2k-(2n-1))x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{2n-1-k}\int\cos((2k-2n+1)x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k+1}\int\cos((2k-2n+1)x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k+1}\int\cos((2k-2n+1)x)dx+\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k+1}\int\cos((2k-2n+1)x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k+1}\int\cos((2k-2n+1)x)dx+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{2n-1-k}(-1)^{2n-1-k}\int\cos((2(2n-1-k)-2n+1)x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n+1)x)dx
+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{2n-1-k}(-1)^{2n-1-k}\int\cos(2n-1-2k)x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n+1)x)dx+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k+1}\int\cos(2k-2n+1)x)dx\right)\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-1-2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k}\int\cos((2k-2n+1)x)dx\\
&=\frac1{2^{2n-2}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{k}(-1)^{k}\dfrac{\sin((2k-2n+1)x}{2k-2n+1}\\
\end{array}
$