# Reduction formula for $\int {x^{n}\over \sqrt{x^2 + a}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Reduction formula for $$I_n =\int {x^{n}\over \sqrt{x^2 + a}} dx$$

---

$\displaystyle u(x) = {x^{n}\over \sqrt{x^2 + a}}, \qquad\qquad v^{'}(x) = 1$

Integrating by parts I get,

$$I_n = {x^{n+1}\over \sqrt{x^2 + a}} - nI_n + \int {x^{n+2}\over (x^2 + a)^{3/2}}dx$$

The problem is $J =\displaystyle\int {x^{n+2}\over (x^2 + a)^{3/2}}dx$, I tried to partial fraction decomposition on ${x^{n+2}\over (x^2 + a)^{3/2}}$ but the result is very messy.

How to write $J$ in terms of $I$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably simpler ways, but let me give one.

Considering $$I_n=\int {x^{n}\over \sqrt{x^2 + a}} dx$$ change variable
$$x=\sqrt a \sinh(y)\implies dx=\sqrt a \cosh(y)\,dy$$ which make $$I_n=a^{n/2}\int\sinh ^n(y)\,dy$$ Now, let $y=iz$ which make $$I_n=i^{n+1}a^{n/2}\int \sin^n(z)\,dz$$ So $$J_n=\frac{I_n}{i^{n+1}a^{n/2}}=\int \sin^n(z)\,dz$$ for which we know the recursion formula (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/integrating-int-sinnx-dx)).

Comment: That was pretty neat but I don't know anything about hyperbolic trigonometric functions.

Comment: @A---B. Don't worry ! This will come very soon. Cheers.

Comment: I hope so. I hate substituting tangent of x when I can substitute hyperbolic sine of x.

Comment: @A---B. Then change variable $x=i \sqrt{a} \sin (z)$

Comment: No other answers were given, so I should select your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate by parts
\begin{align}
I_n &= \int {x^{n}\over \sqrt{x^2 + a}} dx= \int x^{n-1}\ d\left( \sqrt{x^2+a}\right)\\
&=\ x^{n-1} \sqrt{x^2+a}-(n-1) \int x^{n-2}\frac{x^2+a}{\sqrt{x^2+a}}dx\\
 &=\ x^{n-1} \sqrt{x^2+a}-(n-1)I_n -(n-1)aI_{n-2}
\end{align}
which yields
$$I_n = \frac{x^{n-1} }n\sqrt{x^2+a}-\frac{(n-1)a}nI_{n-2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take $a=b^2$ and first of all get rid of $b$. Then do integration by parts of what left to get a recursion formula.

Comment: $$\int {x^{n+2}\over b^3((x/b)^2 + 1)^{3/2}} dx $$ should I do a substitution of $x/b = \tan u$ ? would not it be messy ?