# Value of $2^{2010} \frac{\int_0^1 x^{1004}(1-x)^{1004} dx}{\int_0^1 x^{1004}(1-x^{2010})^{1004} dx}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of the following Integral

$$2^{2010} \frac{\int_0^{1} x^{1004}(1-x)^{1004} dx}{\int_0^{1} x^{1004}(1-x^{2010})^{1004} dx}$$

Because it is in power of 1004 i am not able to find the correct substitution.

Comment: For the denominator, $x^{1005}=u$ and for the numerator $x=\sin t$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

For the numerator, consider
$$I_n=\int x^n(1-x)^n\,dx$$ Let $x=\sin^2(t)$, $dx=2\sin(t)\cos(t)$ to make 
$$I_n=\frac 1 {2^{2n}}\int \sin^{2n+1}(2t)\,dt$$ Have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/integrating-int-sinnx-dx).

Comment: This can be solved more easily by the application of the beta function.

Comment: I agree with you for sure. I did not know if the OP already knew it. Cheers :-)