# How do you calculate this integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ {e^{\sin t}}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the  Integral: $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ {e^{\sin t}}\ dt $$

I've found results for this which involve an infinite series which becomes increasingly complicated and other series that involve more integrals. Ideally the solution should be a well defined constant.

Comment: See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), in particular eq. (5).

Comment: $2\pi I_0(1)$ where $I_\alpha(x)$ is the [modified bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2906764/calculating-the-nth-digit-of-non-analytic-integral) is similar

Comment: @Nimish I have added some details of calculations with Simpson's rule to my answer. I hope it helps you a little.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taylor series of $$e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
For $$x = \sin t$$

$$e^{\sin t} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^n t}{n!}$$
Let's integrate
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\sin t} \ dt = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ n!}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^n t \ dt$$

The integral could be computed using the method mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/integrating-int-sinnx-dx), i.e. using integration by parts as [they did here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/integrating-int-sinnx-dx). You will end up with a relation of linking $I_n = \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^n t \ dt$ with $I_{n-2}$, and by induction or recursion, you could show that 
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\sin^n t \ dt = \pi \frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-3}{n-2} \ldots \frac{3}{4} \qquad n = 2k$$
and zero for odd $n$.

Comment: To clarify the final integral requires the condition n>4. And is there any way to synthesize the answer to get the one Nosrati got?

Comment: You could even use contour integration to get the last result, substituting $z = e^{it}$: if $\gamma$ is the unit circle in the complex plane transversed once and counterclockwise,
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^n t\ dt = \int_\gamma \left(\frac{z - 1/z}{2i} \right)^n \frac{dz}{iz} = \dots = 2\pi i \mathrm{Res}( \cdots )$$

Comment: And to address your final question, take a look at the properties of double factorials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Comment: Taking what giobrach said, this would be the answer.

Answer (score 9):

With [Modified Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) 
$$I_\alpha(x)=\dfrac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi e^{x\cos t}\cos\alpha t\ dt$$
then
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\sin t}\ dt
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\cos t}\ dt \\
&= \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{\cos t}\ dt+\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{-\cos t}\ dt \\
&= \pi I_0(1)+\pi I_0(-1) \\
&= 2\pi I_0(1) \\
&= 2\pi\sum_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{2^{2n}n!^2}
\end{align}

Comment: The answer is definitely right. But personally I currently don't have the skills to understand the Bessel function apart from utilizing its results. Is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Without bessel functions you may see Ahmad Bazzi solution, Is it suitable way for you?

Comment: @Nosrati Please ignore my ignorance but how would you solve your final summation to get a constant ?

Comment: @paulplusx do you want a real number?

Comment: @Nosrati Yes, something like $7.95493$ (that's what [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B2%CF%80%7De%5E%7Bsint%7Ddt) suggests)

Comment: It could be hard, and a good question. I think about it.

Comment: @Nosrati Thanks, I would really love to know that. I pointed this out because the question is a *definite* integral (so it would be ideal to have a constant as an answer).

Comment: With asymptotic behavior $x\to0$
$$2\pi I_0(1)=2\pi J_0(i)\sim2\pi \dfrac{1}{\Gamma(1)}\sim2\pi \sim6.3$$
though there would be a better approximation.

Comment: What do you think about Simpson's rule for this particular integral ? with $n=6$ you get a pretty good approximation of $7.954$.

Comment: @paulplusx I think you add Simpson's rule details to your solution, may it helps someone.

Comment: Sure I'll do that.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule) to approximate this integral.

Below is the formula for using Simpson's $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$ rule

$$\int _{a}^{b}f(x)\,dx \approx \frac {\Delta x}{3}\left(f(x_{0})+4f(x_{1})+2f(x_{2})+4f(x_{3})+2f(x_{4})+\cdots +4f(x_{n-1})+f(x_{n})\right)$$

Where $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_i=a+i\Delta x$.

$n$ is the number of equal intervals you want to take. The bigger $n$ is, the better is the accuracy of your solution.

So if we take $n=6$, $b=2\pi$, $a=0$, we have $\displaystyle\Delta x=\frac{2\pi-0}{6}=\frac{\pi}{3}$, hence we have end points as $\displaystyle a=0, \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{2 \pi}{3}, \pi, \frac{4 \pi}{3}, \frac{5 \pi}{3}, 2 \pi=b$.

Using Simpson's $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}$ rule, we have:

$\begin{align*}\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\ {e^{\sin t}}dt&\approx\frac{\Delta x}{3}\left(f(x_{0})+4f(x_{1})+2f(x_{2})+4f(x_{3})+2f(x_{4})+4f(x_{5})+f(x_{6})\right)\\&\approx\frac{\pi}{3*3}\left(f(0)+4f\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)+2f\left(\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)+4f\left(\frac{3\pi}{3}\right)+2f\left(\frac{4\pi}{3}\right)+4f\left(\frac{5\pi}{3}\right)+f(2\pi)\right)\\&\approx\frac{\pi}{9}\left(1+9.50977070094466+4.75488535047233+...+1.68248010421646+1\right)\\&\approx7.95464392016463\end{align*}$

And there you have it: $$\int_{t=0}^{2\pi}\ {e^{\sin t}}dt\approx7.95\text{ (correct to 2 decimal places).}$$

Like I have mentioned above if we keep increasing the number of intervals ($n$), the above approximation will get closer and closer to the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin(x)}dx$$
we know that: $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
so:
$$e^{\sin(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^n(x)}{n!}$$
this is not very nice. We know that:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\sin(x)}dx=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos(x)}dx$$
therefore:
$$I^2=\left(\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin(x)}dx\right)\left(\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos(x)}dx\right)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin(x)+\cos(y)}dxdy=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}re^{\sin(r\cos(\theta))+\cos(r\sin(\theta))}drd\theta$$
I was thinking a substition could be made so that the inside of the $\sin(r\cos(\theta))$ and $\cos(r\sin(\theta))$ would be more similar but nothing appears to be possible.@Nosrati appears to have the easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use Bessel function directly, use, as in answers and comments $$e^{\sin (t)} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^n( t)}{n!}$$ and the fact that
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^n(t)\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \left(1+(-1)^n\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$$ that is to say $0$ if $n$ is odd. So
$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\sin (t)}\,dt = 2 \sqrt{\pi }\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{ \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{(n!)^2}$$