# How to prove the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} x^{-1}\sin (x+x^{-1})\,dx=\pi J_0(2)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x}dx=\pi J_0(2)$$

I'v found:$$I=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin \left(x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{x}dx=3\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin \left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)}{x}dx=...=n\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin \left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)}{x}dx$$
But I still wouldn't prove the integral，can someone help me?

Comment: You might want to include a definition of $J_0$.

Comment: Can we use $J_0(2)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!^2}$ ?

Comment: @robjohn I just use http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/? to do this.

Comment: so you have no idea what $J_0(2)$ means? It is just something that W/A spat out?

Comment: @robjohn        wow! great,but I don't know how to use it?

Comment: You can click the info button at the bottom right corner to learn more about said $J_0$ function.

Comment: @FrankW. I know the Bessel function, but do'nt prove this closed form.

Comment: @FofX [In this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) several definitions are provided (but I don't know if they are immediately useful here).

Comment: For registered users sometimes [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) provides a step-by-step solution.

Comment: As another example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2911545/132192) a straightforward definition of another Bessel function is used to solve an integral.

Comment: See:  G.N.Watson. A Treatise on the theory of bessel functions.pg183-184

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin\left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)\frac{dx}{x} = 2\int_{1}^{+\infty}\sin\left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)\frac{dx}{x}=2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(2\cosh(nz))\,dz $$
equals, in the improper-Riemann sense,
$$ \frac{2}{n}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(2\cosh u)\,du = \frac{2}{n}\underbrace{\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(2v)}{\sqrt{v^2-1}}\,dv}_{\text{constant}}. $$
In order to derive an explicit expression for the involved constant it is practical to study the function
$$ f(a) = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(a v)}{\sqrt{v^2-1}}\,dv$$
by integration by parts and differentiation under the integral sign, or just through the Laplace transform. 
We have
$$ (\mathcal{L}f)(s) = \int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{v}{(s^2+v^2)\sqrt{v^2-1}}\,dv=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{1+s^2}}=g(s) $$
and by the extended binomial theorem
$$ g(s) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \binom{2n}{n}}{4^n s^{2n+1}} $$
such that
$$ f(a) = (\mathcal{L}^{-1}g)(a) = \frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \binom{2n}{n}}{4^n (2n)!}a^{2n}=\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n a^{2n}}{4^n n!^2} = \frac{\pi}{2}\,J_0(a)$$
by the series definition of $J_0$. By putting everything together we get:

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin\left(x^n+\frac{1}{x^n}\right)\frac{dx}{x} = \color{red}{\frac{\pi\,J_0(2)}{n}}\approx \frac{1105}{1571 n}. $$

Comment: Thank you for your beutiful answer!

Answer (score 3):

Probably the simplest way to see this is to sub $x=e^t$.  The result is that the integral is seen to be equal to

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dt \, \sin{(2 \cosh{t})} = 2 \operatorname{Im} \int_0^{\infty} dt \, e^{i 2 \cosh{t}} = 2 \operatorname{Im} K_0(-i 2)$$

and use the fact that

$$K_0(-i 2) = \frac{\pi}{2} \left (Y_0(2) + i J_0(2) \right ) $$

and the result follows.

Comment: Thank you for your beutiful answer!