# Is there a law for the anti- derivative of $sin^n(x)$？

Tags: integration

I have calculated the antiderivative of $sin^n(x)$ from $n=1$ to $n=20$ by software. Now I want to know if there are some laws about them？

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/integrating-int-sinnx-dx

Comment: I added a answer to the linked question: if
$I_n(x)
=\int \sin^n(x)dx
$,
then
$I_{n}(x)
=\frac1{2^{n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \rfloor}\binom{n}{k}(-1)^{k}\dfrac{\sin((2k-n)x)}{2k-n}+\text{(if n is even)}\binom{n}{n/2}\dfrac{(-1)^{n/2}x}{2^{n}}
$.