# Solving $\int \sin^6(x)\cos^2(x)dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

$$\int \sin^6(x)\cos^2(x)dx$$
$t=\sin x$ or $\cos x$ doesn't work obviously

In general, how do I approach the integrals of the form -
$$\int \sin^m(x)\cos^n(x)dx ;  x,y \in 2n, n\in \mathcal{I^+}$$

I'm ruling out the possibility of taking $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$ and applying sine reduction formula, since its just tedious for higher $m$(s)

**Edit:** I'm not "accepting" any answer, since every answer is equally good and I'm trying to get as many approaches/answers as possible :-)

Comment: Sometimes tedium is the only way.  Perhaps it is worth a try to see what turns up...

Comment: @PeterForeman Im sorry, Fourier series is way beyond the scope of my knowledge

Comment: @abiessu thats double the work. First we have to expand and multiply a lot, and then apply reduction formula for so many terms.

Answer (score 3):

[Bioche's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules) recommend $u=\tan x$, giving$$\int\sin^6x\cos^2xdx=\int\sin^6x\cos^4xdu=\int\tan^6x\cos^{10}xdu=\int\frac{u^6du}{(1+u^2)^5}.$$Now it's an exercise in partial fractions. No matter how you do it, [the result is messy](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+u%5E6%2F%281%2Bu%5E2%29%5E5).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does get really messy!

Comment: +1 for Bioche's rules, also if I prefer the answer by @zwim

Comment: @enzoib Come to think of it, so do I, even though the answer by sirous has the advantage of not requiring the reader to know about complex numbers.

Comment: In the case of a single $\sin^n x$ or $\cos^n x,$ with even $n,$ me too try to use duplication formulae, but for a product of even powers it becomes quickly a mess

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is to linearize this expression using $\begin{cases}\cos(x)^2=\left(\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^2\\\sin(x)^6=\left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}\right)^6\end{cases}$

You will get a sum of $e^{\pm nx}$ terms than you can then recombine to get $\cos(nx)$ or $\sin(nx)$ terms.

$-\frac 1{256}e^{8ix}+\frac 1{64}e^{6ix}-\frac 1{64}e^{4ix}-\frac 1{64}e^{2ix}+\frac 5{128}-\frac 1{64}e^{-2ix}-\frac 1{64}e^{-4ix}+\frac 1{64}e^{-6ix}-\frac 1{256}e^{-8ix}$

$ = -\frac 1{128}\cos(8x)+\frac 1{32}\cos(6x)-\frac 1{32}\cos(4x)-\frac 1{32}\cos(2x)+\frac 5{128}$

Now this is straightforward to integrate.

Comment: That's elegant! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The standard methods for monomials is $\sin$ and $\cos$ depends on the values of the exponents:

- if the exponent of $\sin$ is odd, set $t=\cos x,\;\mathrm dt=-\sin x\,\mathrm dx$. If the exponent of $\cos$ is odd, set $t=\sin x,\;\mathrm dt=\sin x\,\mathrm dx$.
- If both exponents are even, it is simpler to linearise the monomial, either with pure trigonometry or with complex numbers. I'll show how it goes with the latter method:

To simplify  the computations, we'll denote $u=\mathrm e^{ix},\;\bar u=\mathrm e^{-ix}$, so that
$$\sin x=\frac{u-\bar u}{2i},\quad\cos x=\frac{u+\bar u}{2}.$$
We'll also apply the following rules:
$$u\,\bar u=1,\quad u^k+\bar u^k=2\cos kx,,\quad u^k-\bar u^k=2i\sin kx.$$
Now the given monomial becomes
\begin{align}
\sin^6x\cos^2x& =\frac{(u-\bar u)^6}{(2i)^6}\,\frac{(u+\bar u)^2}{2^2}=-\frac{(u-\bar u)^4(u^2-\bar u)^2}{256}\\
&= -\frac{(u^4-4u^2+6-4\bar u^2+\bar u^4)(u^4-2+\bar u^4)}{256}\\
&=-\frac1{256}\Bigl[(u^8-4u^6+6u^4-4u^2+1)-(2u^4-8u^2+12-8\bar u^2+2\bar u^4)\\
&\hspace{6em}+(1-4\bar u^2+6\bar u^4-4\bar u^6 +\bar u^8\Bigr] \\
&=-\frac1{128}\bigl[\cos 8x-4\cos 6x+4\cos 4x +4\cos 2x -5\bigr].
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If you are  patient enough you can use following identities:

$$\cos^2 (x)=\frac{1}2(1+\cos (2x))$$

$$\sin^6(x)=\frac{1}{16}[9(1-\cos 2x)/2+(1-\cos 6x)/2-3(\cos 2x-\cos 4x)]$$

Now multiply and reduce the product to  algebraic sum of $\sin kx$ or $\cos tx$ and integrate.

Comment: This is very similar to the method proposed by @zwim but without complex numbers!

Comment: @DatBoi, just wanted to show the method for this particular case.. of course method proposed by zwin is a general solution and is great for linearization.

Comment: Of course ;---)

Answer (score 1):

There are a recursive formulas:

$$\int\sin^nax\cos^max\space dx =-\frac{\sin^{n-1}ax \cos^{m+1}ax}{a(n+m)}+\frac{n-1}{n+m}\int\sin^{n-2}ax \cos^m ax \space dx$$

(lowering exponent $n$; $m$ and $n > 0$),

$$=\frac{\sin^{n+1}ax \cos^{m-1}ax}{a(n+m)}+\frac{m-1}{n+m}\int\sin^{n}ax \cos^{m-2} ax \space dx$$

(lowering exponent $m$; $m$ and $n>0$).

Comment: I assume that "lowering exponent" means the smaller of the two exponents?

Comment: It is up to you, but sure we will use the one which will take a less time to get the solution...

Comment: I understand.Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @AntonVrdolijak Can you give me some hints on how to manipulate the integral part of integration by parts to get the desired result?

Comment: To @DatBoi: I borrowed above formulas from Handbook of Mathematics (authors: I.N. Bronshtein · K.A. Semendyayev · G.Musiol · H.Muehlig)...

Answer (score 1):

Apply the recursion

$$I_n=\int \sin^n{x} \ dx = -\frac{1}{n} \cos{x} \sin^{n - 1}{x} + \frac{n - 1}{n} I_{n-2}$$

to integrate
\begin{align}
&\int \sin^6x\cos^2xdx = I_6-I_8=-\frac18I_6+\frac18\cos x\sin^7x\\
 =& -\frac5{48}I_4 +\frac18\cos x\left( \frac1{6}\sin^5x+\sin^7x\right)\\
 =&-\frac{15}{256}I_2 +\frac18\cos x\left(\frac5{32}\sin^3x+\frac1{6}\sin^5x+\sin^7x \right)\\
 =&-\frac{15}{512}x +\frac18\cos x\left(\frac{15}{64}\sin x+ \frac5{32}\sin^3x+\frac1{6}\sin^5x+\sin^7x \right)\\
\end{align}
[Integrating $\int \sin^n{x} \ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112687/integrating-int-sinnx-dx)